# How to get the device manufacturer name attached to the serial port

Tags: serial-port, winapi

I want to know a method in Win32 to get the device manufacturer name attached with the serial port.

I have already tried the SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty API with the SPDRP_MFG 
option but getting manufacturer name which is mentioned by the driver. What I want manufacturer name associated with the device not with the driver.

My Device is a USB device and appearing as a USB Serial Port(COM4) in the device manager.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A serial device does not send this type of meta data to the computer.  There is no hand-shaking done like in a USB connection where the device identifies itself.  With a serial device, the computer just starts sending or receiving data.

Comment: Actually my device is also a USB device but appearing as a "USB Serial port (COM4)". Can I get manufacturer name now, any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Run the USBView sample which comes with the WDK to get the manufacturer name and other information about the USB devices.